# How to subtract 1 year from a calculated column in SQL

Tags: sql

In SQL through below given logic I am deriving one date

```
add_months(to_date(DateField,'yyyymmdd'),

           trunc(months_between(TRUNC(sysdate), to_date(DateField,'yyyymmdd'))/12)*12
          ) DATE_1
```

How I can subtract 1 year from DATE_1.

For e.g. IF am getting say date_1 = 13/02/2019 then how i will get out put as  13/02/2018 in date_2 column.

Answer (score 0):

Try
**select date_add( to_date('13/02/2019','dd/mm/yyyy'),interval 1 year)..**

Answer (score 0):

add the logic in stored proc and then add below line:

```
SELECT date_t(year, 1, date_1) AS date_2
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this function  return (DateAdd("13/02/2019", "1" , , , -1)) and refer the link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41183_01/DR/Dateadd.html